# How to consume a RESTful web service using browser technologies

Tags: jquery, html, rest

So i've developed a simple Java restful webservice and it's running on http://localhost:8080/testProject/rest/items.

When I navigate to that URL in a broswer I get XML back.

So what would be the best way to consume the Web Service and display the result in a user friendly way, in a table for example.

Should I use basic HTML or jquery or something for this?

I will also be looking to post parameters to the web service in the future.

Thanks

Comment: Web services are not intended for user interaction, so why do you want to make its description (the xml you see in the browser) "more user friendly"?

Comment: Sorry I am asking the easiest way to consume the service in a browser

Comment: @flexer7661 are you set on a technology or are you asking what should you use as a framework?

Comment: This will only work on the same localhost:8080 location unless you implement `CORS` (google for it). You should use a combination of html and javascript; jQuery may make the javascript side of it easier.

Comment: No i'm not set on a technology but i'm looking for the easiest to use.

Comment: @Kevin B so if I was to write a web client for a remote web service, I would need this?

Comment: @flexer7661 If you were to write a remote service that returns XML and is meant to be used by web clients, yes, you would have to implement `CORS`, or you can have it also return JSONP (not to be confused with JSON).

Comment: So implementing CORS sounds to me as if I shouldn't be consuming a RESTful web service this way? Feels like i'm doing something non-standard.... If I wanted to write some application for a web browser that consumes RESTful web services created by someone else what would be the normal thing to do?

Answer (score 1):

To display XML files nicely in the browser, XSLT is what you're looking for. You can use XSLT to transform XML documents into HTML, so you can display nice tables and pretty styles. Wikipedia on XSLT:

> XSLT (Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations) is a declarative, XML-based language used for the transformation of XML documents. The original document is not changed; rather, a new document is created based on the content of an existing one.[2] The new document may be serialized (output) by the processor in standard XML syntax or in another format, such as HTML or plain text.[3] XSLT is most often used to convert data between different XML schemas or to convert XML data into web pages or PDF documents

It's quite simple to get started. I recommend using W3Schools: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Hope that helps

Comment: thanks but I think i was unclear. I was more asking about the best way to consume a RESTful web service in a browser application. I.e best technologies/practices

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Comment: Is this standard practice even for web services that are remote, i.e someone else has created.What would be the best way to consume another organisations Web service for a browser application

Comment: In general, AJAX requests are only allowed back to the server that served up the page, due to the same origin policy. There are workarounds, for example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP . You might also consider creating a proxy that you can call from your web server. The proxy would then use cURL or an equivalent to make an actual request to the remote service.

Comment: Yeah so these seem like work arounds. But if someone asked you tomorrow to develop a browser based application that consumes a RESTful remote web service what would your implementation choices be? Am i missing something?

Comment: They are workarounds for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy . I already told you my implementation choices...

Comment: By workaround i mean something that works but isn't really how it should be. I want to know what an experienced web developer would do in this scenario. So the standard thing they would do is to use JSONP or create a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Restful services are meant only to consume data from the server and display those to the user. If you are also looking to post data back to the server, you may want to look at other options...(curl, soap, xml-rpc) with proper auth checks so that malicious data is not posted back to the server / database.

Now, back to your original question, you have got an xml response back and you want to show the results to your users, you can use [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) to do that, or you can just parse the xml on the server side and use to display it to your users.